# Speed issues with ngRepeat. Is it possible to reuse a DOM-part in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I am displaying a list with a lot of data and it is getting very slow very fast (>5 entries = too slow). I tinkered around a little bit and found that not the amount of data is the problem but the many DOM elements that are generated.

I show a table with just some meta information. For each table row there are two more hidden table rows that include all the detail data and an edit form. Clicking on a row opens the detail info and clicking on some edit button switches to the edit row.
A simplified plunkr without the edit portion is available [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UMe7Us6qTCp51YL5cA1M).

The problem is that for each entry there are three rows generated that include a ton of tags and data. Pagination is no solution since the problem already manifests itself in a significant way with as few as 4 or 5 entries. I could load the detail data dynamically but I found that the bottleneck are the many tags that ng-repeat has to create. (Am I mistaken here?)
When I cut out the detail and edit portion the page loads reasonably fast even with 10+ entries.

A solution could be to write the detail and edit part once and hide it and then dynamically shift it around to the according entry. I know that direct DOM manipulation is frowned upon in Angular. Is there a better solution? [A plunkr that illustrates the idea](http://plnkr.co/edit/q3I4dy8baalB0Q892w68)

Comment: first thing you can try is to use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`, in your case, it will cut down the number of elements to half... and the second thing you can do to speed up the app, make sure there is no irrelevant data on the `$scope`, every piece of data you attach to scope, is cutting the performance

Comment: Whoa ng-if seems to do the trick. So ng-if only creates the elements when its true whereas ng-show creates them but hides them?

Comment: yes, exactly. `ng-if` adds the element to the DOM only if expression is true, in case of `ng-show` it is always there, and directive just toggles `display:none` style

Answer (score 0):

I looked into angular.element and updated the second plunkr with the solution. I am still not sure if there is not a more elegant solution. I will implement it and see if the performance issues are resolved by it.

Moving of the DOM part:

```
<td id="detailPiece">
  Reuse this piece of DOM? Can it be done?<br />
  Tons of detail information, with edit capability etc.<br />
  {{detailItem.detail}}
</td>
```

is achieved by

```
angular.element('#detail'+index).append( angular.element('#detailPiece') );
```

Still looks like a 'hacky' solution to me with the empty table row and all.